# transferring info from phone to sd card

Tags: storage, sd-card

I have put in a new sd card. I can't find out how to transfer apps & information that has been backed up. I followed instructions about storage sense but can't get how to retrieve info.

Comment: Have you used any apps such as Transfer My data to backup your information to SD card.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is using your computer.
You need to have a Windows XP/Vista/7/8(.1)/10 with an internet connection.

- Put the SD Card in your Windows Phone
- Use a phone-to-USB cable. When it's connected, make sure the Windows Phone is installed before using it.
- Go to the File Manager and go to (My) Computer.
- Right click on Windows Phone and select Open/Explore
- Normally, you should see 2 items: Phone, and the SD card. Double click on Phone and copy the files you want to transfer
- After you've copied the files, put them in the same location on the SD card. If the folder isn't created yet, make it.

Answer (score 0):

When you back up your files, applications, and others thing, all that will go to phone memory. So then you need to change destination of your apps or files. For that you need to go in storage, for W10M you need to change location where you want to save all your files if you have SD card set up all to be saved on SD card. For changing destination of your apps you need to click (in storage app) on [my phone](http://prntscr.com/b0be0l), then you will get full list of your apps and for change destination of them you need to click on app which you want to move on SD card, you will get pop up message to confirm changing destination.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can transfer files from phone to SD card.

One of the way by using Microsoft's free app named [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/files/9wzdncrfj3pl). Using this app, you can move the contents from phone to SD card or vice versa.

Check these [link-1](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/move-apps-phone-memory-sd-card-windows-phone-8-1) & [link-2](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/phones-and-hardware/use-an-sd-card-to-add-space) to get clear idea.